# Flurry IOS SDK Error - Undefined symbol: ___isPlatformVersionAtLeast

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

When I try to build my app, I get the following error

```
Showing Recent Messages
:-1: Undefined symbol: ___isPlatformVersionAtLeast
```

I tried cleaning the build, reinstalling the pods, but nothing works. Can someone please help?

I'm using XCode V10.3, IOS V 11.2.
Here's my pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.2'

  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Minuteapp
  pod 'FacebookCore'
  pod 'FacebookLogin'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FacebookShare'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'FolioReaderKit'
  pod 'AppAuth','~> 1.2.0'
  pod 'SwiftMessages' , '7.0.0'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Promises' 
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Branch'
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK' #Analytics Pod
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryAds' #Advertising Pod (requires Analytics)
  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryMessaging'
  pod 'ApphudSDK'
  pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'AQPlayer'
  pod 'DeviceKit'
  pod "SwiftRater"
  pod "STPopup"
  pod 'iOSDropDown'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Flurry SDK was built with Xcode 11.

Options:

- Upgrade to Xcode 11
- Ask Flurry to support Xcode 10.3
- Use an old version of the Flurry SDK that was built with Xcode 10